# Jquery expand from external link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks on a link from one page, it goes to another page that has a simple jquery collapsed text and expands (un-collapses) the text. My attempt is with the code below:

```
$(function() {
  var elem = $('#expand-4' + location.hash); 
  $('#expand-4-text').slideToggle('fast', function() {
     // Animation complete.
  });
  $('#expand-4').toggleClass('expand-4-expanded');
});
```

It does not work though.  Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Whats the html? can you post a demo on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Yes.  Here is part of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/5WTBV/

Answer (score 0):

You're calling "slideToggle()" on a part of the page that's already visible, so jQuery hides it for you — that's what "slideToggle()" is supposed to do.  You can make it *show* the text instead by simply hiding it first:

```
$('#expand-4-text').hide().slideToggle('fast');
```